# Hola necesito ayuda con un control Qtableview en python

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con Python y Pyqt5  obtengo los datos de una tabla en mysql en el Qtableview con el model pero no puedo sumar el valor de una de las columnas que obtengo en el table. necesito asignarlo a la propiedad text de label.

gracias

```
self.model= QSqlTableModel(self)
            self.model.setTable("tablaunion")
            self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
            self.model.select()
            self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)
            #self.model.setFilter("Centro_de_Costo like '"+self.ui.comboBox.currentText()+"%'")
            self.model.setFilter("Fecha_Carga between '"+ Fecha1 +"%' and '"+ Fecha2 +"%' and Centro_de_Costo like '"+self.ui.comboBox.currentText()+"%' order by Fecha_Carga")
```

Comment: Puedes añadir parte del codigo que estas desarrollando? Será mas facil ayudarte :)

Comment: Julio bienvenido a [es.so]. Te recomiendo que te mires [tour] y [ask] para conocer por encima el funcionamiento del sitio y cómo realizar preguntas con mayor probabilidad de obtener buenas respuestas. Para poder orientarte es necesario  que aportes tu código o al menos un [mcve], que expliques mejor el problema y cuál es la salida esperada, por qué no puedes hacer lo que quieres, que errores te dá o que hace que no debería hacer. Usa el botón [`editar`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/110967/edit) y agrega todo lo que consideres oportuno. Un saludo.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Mira aquí [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Perdon soy nuevo en Stackoverflow. Bueno el codigo esta agregado pero no se como sumar el valor de una de las columnas que obtengo en el table. necesito asignarlo a la propiedad text de label.

Comment: Hola ya ingrese codigo el campo "Cantidad_Litros" no figura en el setfilter pero es uno de los que aparece en el Qtableview. necesito sumar sus valores y colocar el resultado en la propiedad text del label

Comment: Perdon por insistir pero alguien tiene alguna idea de como puedo resolver esto....gracias